# assertion fails-- Check a field is greater than

Tags: java

Im trying to use a assert stmt to check if a value is greater than 1 but its not working as expected.

```
public class asserttest {
    static void methoda(int i){
        assert (i > 1);
        System.out.println("This is methoda");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        methoda(-1);
    }
}
```

Output:
This is methoda

Expected output:-
assertionerror

I was able to fix it by enabling the assertions.

Comment: It's hard to know what's wrong as you haven't said what you expected, what happened, or how you're running the code (with assertions enabled or not).

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you're getting confused by assertions not being enabled by default. Use the `-enableassertions` command line option:

```
java -enableassertions asserttest
```

You can also limit assertions to specific packages, and specify packages to *disable* using `-disableassertions` too.

Personally I prefer to *unconditionally* validate parameter values, precisely because of this - I don't like the idea of running the code in a "safe" mode in test, but then letting it loose in production with the safety off. It's like learning to drive with a seatbelt on, but then entering an F1 race without any protection...

Comment: If I could I would give another +1 for the race metaphor :)

Answer (score 0):

*You should never use assertions on parameters* or any input value in general.

Assertions are meant to describe *invariants* that ought to be always `true`. Therefore they can be switched off for performance reasons. You have to enable them, e.g. by using the `-ea` JVM option.

But inputs to a method should always be checked so use

```
if(i<=1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("i must be >1");
```